# Beginner C# Linq: looping through kvp in a dictionary<>

Tags: c#, linq, loops, dictionary, key-value

Is this

```
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in myDic.Select(x => x).ToList())
    {

    }
```

and this

```
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in myDic.ToList()) 
    {

    }
```

the same?

I saw this code and was confused. Does the "Select(x => x) part just there for convenience, so that later it can be turned into something like (x => x != 0) ?

Comment: What language is this? Please edit the question to add the language as a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Select(x => x)` doesn't really make a difference. However, the `ToList()` creates a new list from the collection. This is different from @NikolaiDante answer in cases where `myDic` is modified inside the loop.

Example:

```
// working fine
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in myDic.ToList())
{
    if (kvp.Value == 0) myDic.Remove(kvp.Key);
}

// throwing exception on Remove
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in myDic)
{
    if (kvp.Value == 0) myDic.Remove(kvp.Key);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

They are exactly the same because

```
Select.(x => x)
```

Will just return the initial list.

Imagine x was instance of `Client`, and you would be writing shipping code and only needed the client addresses.

Then you would go with

```
Select.(x => x.Address)
```

which would return a `List<Address>` instead of `List<Client>` therefore decoupling your method from the `Client` class (why would shipping care about the client himself, it only needs the address)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Here's a [runnable fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/q9sdFf).

Additionally,

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in myDic) 
{

}
```

would work too as you dont need to .ToList() to itterate over a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are exactly the same in the results they produce

But, you can just use :

```
foreach (var item in myDic)
{

}
```

because Dictionary implements IEnumerable and therefore you can iterate over it

The 2 ways you wrote just adds unnecessary work converting the dictionary to another collection